# working with groupby multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, group-by, multiple-columns

I have 3 columns in a dataframe, as:

User_ID, Product_Category_1 and Corresponding Purchase amount.

I am trying to group by based on User_ID and Product_Category_1 and selecting the average of Purchase amount.

So output dataframe will have: User_ID,Product_Category_1 and Avg_Purchase.

This is not working for me:

```
x=train_bk.groupby(["User_ID","Product_Category_1"],as_index=False)['Purchase'].transform('mean')
```

This gives me a series of the mean value of Purchase for each row. However I need to keep only the unique User_ID and Product_Category_1 combination

```
   x1 = train_bk.select(Average(train_bk.User_ID), train_bk.Product_Category_1,
          group_by=(train_bk.User_ID,train_bk.Product_Category_1))
```

I tried this from sql package. But it throws error: "name 'Average' is not defined". Also is there a good package in python that has SQL syntax similar to Teradata or MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, This seems to be working:

```
   x = train_bk.groupby(["User_ID","Product_Category_1"],as_index=False)['Purchase'].mean()
```